# Can't resolve flutter native communication error - Unhandled Exception No implementation found for method on Channel

Tags: java, android, flutter, cross-platform, flutter-platform-channel

*I have just Copied the code from flutter.dev and modified it and getting following error*

**E/flutter ( 2639): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method myNativeFunction on channel My Channel)**
*
I want to print a message from Native java code to Flutter UI
*

```
This is my Main.dart
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  static const platform = const MethodChannel('My Channel');

  String message = "No Message from Native App";
  Future<void> callNative() async {
    String messageFromNative = "No message from Native";
    try {
      messageFromNative = await platform.invokeMethod('myNativeFunction');
      print(messageFromNative);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("error + '${e.message}' ");
      message = "Failed to get Native App function: '${e.message}'.";
    }
    setState(() {
      message = messageFromNative;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Native Demo'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(message),
              RaisedButton(child: Text('Native '), onPressed: callNative)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
This is my MainActivity.java
```

```
package com.example.batterylevel;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

    public static final String CHANNEL="MyChannel";

   @Override
   public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
       super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
       new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
               .setMethodCallHandler(
                       (call, result) -> {
                           
                           if(call.method.equals("myNativeFunction"))
                           {
                               String messageToFlutter=myNativeFunction();
                               result.success(messageToFlutter);
                           }else {
                               result.notImplemented();
                               Log.d("RD","else");
                           }

                       }
               );
   }

    String myNativeFunction()
    {
        return "Message from Android";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `MainActivity`, method channel name should match the method channel name defined in dart.

**Dart**

```dart
static const platform = const MethodChannel('My Channel');
```

**Java**

```java
public static final String CHANNEL = "My Channel"; // on dart side it's "My Channel", but you've written "MyChannel"
```

Comment: Thank you. Changed the name in two places but the error persists, Can you please help. static const platform = const MethodChannel('channel');                                                  
 public static final String CHANNEL="channel";

Comment: You need to rebuild the app and rerun it, if any changes are made on platform side code. Hot reload and hot restart doesn't work when changes are made in native code.

Comment: cleaned flutter project, uninstalled app from phone and tried running again but still the error persists, any thought?

Comment: Ask a new question on SO with proper details.